# <a href> a un identificador con margen

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css3

Mi pregunta es si se puede hacer un a `href` a un id pero que te mande 5px mas arriba o 10px por ejemplo:

```
<a href = "#nosotros"></a>
<div id = "nosotros"></div>
```

Que se vea de esta manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y no pegado arriba como aquí
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que es posible hacerlo con jQuery. Incluso lo puedes animar un poco. 
Con estos elementos:

Le agregaría algo así:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id='hola'><h2>Hola</h2></div>
<a data-href='#hola' href='#'>Ir a hola</a>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('a').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var div = $(this).data('href');
            var y = $(div).offset().top - 50;
            $('body,html').stop(true,true).animate({                                
                scrollTop: y
            },1000);
        });
    });

</script>
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Muchas Gracias amigo sirvio 100% (Y) EXCELENTE :D

Answer (score 1):

La propiedad que te puede servir es `padding`.

**Ejemplo CSS**

```css
.big {
  height: 600px;
}

#nosotros {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#nosotros">Nosotros</a>
<div class="big"></div>
<div id="nosotros">
  <h1>Nosotros</h1>
</div>
<div class="big"></div>
```

Sin embargo, no es viable ya que si quieres darle un margen superior de 50px, tendrías que darle un `padding-top: 50px` lo cual se vería horrible. Lo mejor sería usar JavaScript para este caso.

**Ejemplo JS**

```js
let anchors = document.querySelectorAll('[anchor]');
[].forEach.call(anchors, function(anchor) {
  anchor.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let el = document.querySelector(this.getAttribute('href'));
    // 50px más abajo
    let top = el.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY - 50;
    window.scrollTo(0, top);
  });
});
```

```css
.big {
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<a anchor href="#nosotros">Nosotros</a>
<div class="big"></div>
<div id="nosotros">
  <h1>Nosotros</h1>
</div>
<div class="big"></div>
```

Comment: Lo tuyo lo soluciona pero si pierde un poco de estetica la página de todos modos gracias :) me diste una idea de como hacerlo

Comment: @SergioCamilo ¿A qué te refieres con **perder la estética** si es código JavaScript?

Answer (score -1):

Claro, coloca este estilo

```
<style>
  a{
   margin-top: 10px;
   display: block;
  }
</style>
```